# How to write a config.json to train a Language model

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, bart

Looking at NLP models on Huggingface I can see that each of those has a so called `config.json` file. Now I want to train a `BART` mode from scratch along [this](https://github.com/octaviaguo/Constrained-Labeled-Data-Generation/tree/main/pipeline_scripts) repo. To do so, I have to "write" a `config.json` myself. Now I can not find any **documentation** what attributes this `config.json` needs to contain.

The training script from the linked [repo](https://github.com/octaviaguo/Constrained-Labeled-Data-Generation/tree/main/pipeline_scripts) (./t5_train/t5_train.py) does fail if the provided config does not contain certain attributes. That way I found out what is missing but without docs I am clueless with what I have to set them.

Example what is among the expected attributes that I dont find a documentation for:

```
training:{
  device: ...,
  optimizer: ...,
  type: ...,
  noise: ...,
  noise_vocab: ...,
}
model:{
  src_lang: ...,
  trg_lang: ...,
  seq2seq: ...,
  dim_word_src: ...,
  n_layers_src: ...,
  bidirectional: ...,
}
```

---

**Does somebody know where I can find a detailed documentation for how to write a `config.json` in particular and a `config.json` for BART in detail?**

---

I allready took a look at https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/configuration but I could not find the attributes that the script expects.